# Error while using superagent in react native ios app

Tags: ios, node.js, react-native

i have made a react native app that used nodejs and express for backend, have cors enabled and which running on android but when i started porting the app for ios and run it in simulator iphone 6, it is running fine but when it comes to hit an api for that i used superagent give me this error.

> ```
> Error: Request has been terminated
> Possible causes: the network is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc.
>     at Request.crossDomainError (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:80241:9)
>     at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:80311:13)
>     at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:10000:15)
>     at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:26063:6)
>     at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:25917:6)
>     at http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:26011:52
>     at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:9233:23)
>     at MessageQueue.__callFunction (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:7213:34)
>     at http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:7104:8
>     at guard (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:7050:1)
> ```

this is how i use superagent

```
const request = require('superagent');

const req = request[options.method.toLowerCase()](options.uri)
        .set(merge({}, options.headers, options.json ? {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} : {}))
        .query(options.qs ? options.qs : {})
        .send(options.json || options.form || options.formData)
      ;
      const requestId = {};

      api.activeRequests.add(requestId);
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        req.end((err, res) => {
          console.log({err, res});
          api.activeRequests.delete(requestId);
          if (err || !res.ok) {
            console.log(res);
            const error = res ? (res.body ? res.body : res) : err;
            reject(error);
          } else {
            resolve(res.body);
          }
        });
      });
```

Need help!

Comment: Please, create a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise it seems unlikely we could help you with the information you posted solely.

Comment: what exact information do you need?

Comment: Put yourself as in the position of someone who tries to answer your question. The more details you can provide them the easiest would be for them to help you. For instance, you have added a small piece of code, but does it compile alone, is it MVCE? You have omitted important details from the pieces of software you use, which versions, which platforms? ... Details matter.

Answer (score 0):

It was due to https request to be posted not http. So as of now since i am in developer mode allowed http to my particular domain.